# What are some good forums or places to discuss original ideas on philosophy?

Tags: truth, descartes

I have a substantive new piece on philosophy which I discuss here:
[A new theory of Truth](https://ng2600.quora.com/A-new-theory-of-Truth)

Reddit/Philosophy mods keep banning my posts for reasons they do not wish to disclose.

I also discuss it in more detail here:
[I think, therefore I am](https://thephilosophyforum.com/discussion/1848/descartess-i-think-therefore-i-am)

I cannot find an outlet to discuss my original ideas on Philosophy at the moment.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: it depends on how serious you are. if you seriously then self publish on print on demand, and let the world burn, like walt whitman but better. you could try to find a philosophy list, as it's much much more likely to incorporate some academic discussion than reddit. alternatively, take some classes and realise you're full of it ;-)

Comment: Dead Serious. What is publish on demand? Could you give that link a read and let me know if I am full of it or not? :) I got no money though.. Student loans.

Comment: ha how should i know if your'e full of it? [lulu](https://www.lulu.com/) is good and does print on demand: it means that a book is printed each time someone orders one, so that the author doesn't need to (i think) invest any money at all, nor find a publisher

Comment: seriously, you may be a savant, or *exceptionally* clever, how would i know? the thing with reading philosophy forums posts, is that you gotta really sell it haha. you don't seem insane anyway, and luck surely isn't a thing here. btw i upvoted cos original is good

Comment: You can just read it :)

Comment: But you are right, I could be full of it as well. I just wish to discuss and find out. Publishing it will not make it be read. It's a convoluted concept.

Comment: well, what i do when i have a stipulatively original *question* is post a "reference request". i.e. *i was reading a lot about tarski and descartes and wondered if anyone has ever claimed that* etc etc. as to readership, i don't think you should care. have you considered hitting up a philosophy professor at your college [they may think you're insane and or stupid]

Comment: It's a lot, I don't even think I can fit into a single question. It will take me a while to get back to college. Professors at my college probably think I am spamming them, due to all the emails before.

Comment: well, if you're studying, it will be a good exercise in study skills, to write an abstract

Comment: I did write an abstract. Just click on the link. But, I do not think it's something they would understand easily as well. You have to engage in a conversation right.

Comment: then why haven't you realised that you're full of it yet? i don't mean that nastily, just suggesting that it sounds like you should study more, before trying anything (else) original

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63976/discussion-between-user3293056-and-novice).

Comment: I know how it sounds like. One thing led to another - I did not aim to write philosophy. This just happened, and I realized I was good at it. I have done a bit of studies on my own, but this is informal philosophy.

Comment: You can also try [Philosophy Forums](http://forums.philosophyforums.com), [Online Philosophy Club](http://onlinephilosophyclub.com/forums) or [I Love Philosophy](http://www.ilovephilosophy.com/viewforum.php?f=27). SE has a number of [active chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com) at any time, some of which might be on philosophy, but usually those grow out of comment threads to questions and answers here.

Comment: I think one of those was broken, others probably not used a lot?